# Windows Visual C++ link to Mesa3D OpenGL

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl, mesa

I have a Windows only application in C++ developed in Visual Studio (2008 at the moment). Its an 3D realtime application that should run on virtual machines where often is no 3d hardware acceleration possible! So I am working with the windows implementation OpenGL32.dll, but it seems to be OpenGL 1.1 and some basic features dont work. 
I want to switch to Mesa3D and use it as software implementation of OpenGL and hope it gives me a higher level of functionality. How can I bin my VSC++ application to Mesa3D? I have already built Mesa3D with SCons and got the mesa opengl32.dll, opengl32.lib etc. Can I just link explicitely link to this library in my visual studio project and its done?

Comment: I read here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15179981/run-opengl-programs-on-older-hardware-through-mesa?rq=1) that it might be enough to place the Mesa3d opengl32.dll in the applications directory, is that correct?

Comment: This is correct, as far as the location where the program and the DLL are installed to is used as the initial startup directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works if you put the opengl32.dll you get from compiled Mesa3D into the applications startup folder (referring to datenwolf, thx). But you further have to take the correct release verion of Mesa. Windows GDI is only supported to release 7.8.2. I first took one of the newest releases (9.0 or newer) and got assertion errors when starting my application. But it works now with a compiled Mesa 7.8.2. By the way, this older release can be compiled directly with Visual Studio as a VC solution is included in Mesa download package there.